# how many times the controller definition block/ main body executes?

Tags: angularjs

I have the following AngularJS code. I have a list of products and I would like to be able define new or update a selected product from the list using one controller. Below is my code.

When I want to edit a product in the list I simply call:

```
$scope.EditProduct = function(prodId) {
    $location.path('/productedit/' + prodId);
};
```

For some reason the main definition body of the newProductController is called twice. I can see function "GetProductForEdit" is called twice. I searched all the project and there is only one call to GetProductForEdit.

Can someone please explain why is this happening? Is this a common behavior in AJ? What am I doing wrong?

Your help is much appreciated.

Mehdi

I am using ngRoute.

```
http://127.0.0.1:5000/static/pages/index.html#/productedit/1

myApp.config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        // some more routes
        ...
        // route for the product edit page
        .when('/productedit/:id', {
            templateUrl: '../pages/productedit.html',
            controller: 'newProductController'
        });
});


myApp.controller('newProductController', ['$scope', '$http', '$routeParams', function ($scope, $http, $routeParams) {
    ....

    $scope.GetProductForEdit = function(prodId) {/* code here is called twice*/};

    $scope.Init = function() {
        if ($routeParams.id != undefined && $routeParams.id != '') {
            $scope.Operation = 'Update';            
            $scope.GetProductForEdit($routeParams.id);
        } else {
            $scope.Operation = 'New';
            $scope.CleanupForm();
        }
    };

    $scope.Init();

}]);
```

Comment: You probably have `ng-controller="newProductController"` in your template

Answer (score 1):

remove `ng-controller="newProductController"` from your html, this is the only case that make your controller run twice, you have already set the controller in your `$routeProvider`, so you don't need to use the `ng-controller` directive !

Comment: oh ... I see thank you so much. Hadn't I asked that, I would not have found it.